# XmlSerializer throwing an InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd

```
InterfaceType interfaceType = new InterfaceType() { definitions = new UnitType[0][] };
try
{
    interfaceType = fileManager.deserialize<InterfaceType>("C:\\Users\\Yogev\\Desktop\\namer_NMC_TILTAN_Interface.xml");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Error deserialize" + ex.ToString());
}
```

This is the creation of the class and the deserialize method calling.

I'm deserializing an auto generated (partial) class from xsd.exe. This is the class:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/IRSSchema.xsd")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("interface", Namespace="http://tempuri.org/IRSSchema.xsd", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class InterfaceType {

private System.Xml.XmlNode[] descriptionField;

private UnitType[][] definitionsField;

private IncludeType[] includeField;

private GroupType[] groupField;

private string nameField;

private string formatField;

private bool isBigEndianField;

private bool isBigEndianFieldSpecified;
```

I'm getting an exception:

```
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'UnitType[]' to 'UnitType'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnitType' to 'UnitType[]'
```

Comment: Show us the XML file. Especially a part with 'definitions' element.

Comment: do you mean the xml file that i'm tring to desirialize?

Answer (score -1):

I tried to serialize your class and actually ran into the same problem. I tried to serialize an one-dimensional array, and it worked. So i recommend you to wrap your two-dimensional array into an array of a container. Then it'll work ;)

Try to add attributes to the array, like:

```
[XmlArray("groupField")]
[XmlArrayItem("GroupType", typeof(GroupType))]
public GroupType[] groupField { get; set; }
```

Comment: There is a constructor with no parameters. The default one.

Comment: I also suspected that it is because of the two dimensional array. but this is an auto-generated file and can not be edited, because it's represent a certain schema of an xml i'm trying to read